# Visual Studio - Change the display name of project in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio

The company I work for gives their projects long names. E.g. `Company.SomeCategory.AnotherCategory.ProjectName`. This takes up lots of space in the SolutionExplorer. Is there some way to change the display name of the project to just `ProjectName`? It is not possible to change the name of the project itself because this is the standard naming convention in this company.